# Cancel button does nothing in MFMailComposeViewController - iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, mfmailcomposer, cancel-button

I've created an MFMailComposeViewController and am able to display it but once I press the cancel button, the cancel button and send button grey out and the action sheet does not appear. Is there anything I am missing?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *m = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[m setToRecipents:@[@"abc@example.com"]];
[m setSubject:@"Subject"];
[m setMessageBody:@"..." isHTML:YES];
[m setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:m animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And here's a screenshot:
[image: Image showing greyed out buttons]So is there something I'm missing or should I file a bug report?

Comment: Did you implement the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol? For example, set the mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self if the current object implements the protocol then implement the required method - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: @deanware yes I did. That's not the issue, the issue is that the action sheet isn't showing.

Comment: @Milo, did you resolve this issue?
I'm getting the same thing, and the code works in iOS 7

Comment: @jaseelder It fixed itself and is currently working properly in the latest beta.

Comment: This question (my question) is now obsolete because it was about the beta version of iOS and the (then apparent) bug is fixed in the latest beta seed.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have found that in iOS8 SDk as MFMailComposeViewController is presented, the Finished event handler fires immediately and the the MFComposeResultEventArgs Result is set to MFMailComposeResult.Cancle.

This may be a bug.